# Flex transparency problem

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript

In development of Flash/Flex application I've came across weird thing: button placed over transparent panel button remains transparent even with alpha="1".

```
<mx:HBox backgroundColor="#444444" alpha="0.8">
    <mx:Button width="34" height="34" toolTip="Home" icon="{homeIcon}" alpha="1" />
</mx:HBox>
```

Is there any way to make button not transparent?

Comment: Share some code!  Are you placing buttons over a panel with absolute positioning?  Or is the button a child of the panel?

Comment: Oops. There was formatting issue, which prevented code from showing. Anyway, it is there now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are setting the alpha of your panel to 0, the children will also be affected.  If you really want a transparent panel with a fully opaque child component, you can create a custom skin that does not draw the background of the panel (although you may need to fill with a fill alpha of 0, otherwise Flash may interpret an empty area as being truly empty).  If it's just the background of the panel (and not the frame/titlebar) that you want transparent, you may be able to simply set the backgroundAlpha of the panel to 0.  Hope that helps.

EDIT: Based on your updated code, you need to change the alpha property on your HBox to backgroundAlpha, then all should work as expected.